# Dynamically choose class from string

Tags: vba, reflection

I'm trying to be able to get an instance of a class based on a passed string ClassName without a bunch of IFs.

Class - ICLass

```
Public Function DoSomething()
End Function
```

Class - Class1

```
Implements IClass
Public Function iclass_dosomething()
    Debug.Print "Done from class1"
End Function
```

Class - Class2

```
Implements IClass
Public Function iclass_dosomething()
    Debug.Print "Done from class2"
End Function
```

Module1 - test module

```
Sub GetInstanceOf(ByVal s As String, ByRef Result As Object)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Dim CodeString As String
    Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    CodeString = "Sub foo(ByRef Result as Object)" & vbCrLf & _
            "Set Result = New " & s & vbCrLf & _
        "End Sub"
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString CodeString

    Application.Run vbComp.Name & ".foo", Result
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub

Sub Testing()
    Dim ClassName As String
    ClassName = "Class2"
    'ClassName = "Class1"
    Dim c As IClass
    Set c = New Class1
    GetInstanceOf ClassName, c
    c.DoSomething
End Sub
```

I'm getting

```
Done from class1
```

I'm expecting

```
Done from class2
```

Comment: Absolutely Awesome!!!  So awesome I had to jack your idea...lol.  This is my version: [Factory Class That Uses Reflection to Instantiate Objects by Class Name](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226726/factory-class-that-uses-reflection-to-instantiate-objects-by-class-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better without the ByRef parameter - just return the instance directly:

```
Function GetInstanceOf(ByVal s As String) As ICLass
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Dim CodeString As String
    Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    CodeString = "Function foo3()" & vbCrLf & _
                     "Set foo3 = New " & s & vbCrLf & _
                 "End Function"

    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString CodeString

    Set GetInstanceOf = Application.Run(vbComp.Name & ".foo3")

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Function

Sub Testing()
    Dim c As ICLass
    Dim ClassName As String
    'ClassName = "Class2"
    ClassName = "Class1"

    Set c = GetInstanceOf(ClassName)

    c.DoSomething
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim. Works as intended.